# How to read "Change in Dividend Accruals"?

Tags: dividends, broker, financial-statements, bank-statements

This is from an Interactive Brokers monthly statement. My question is, how much of the AUD 36.06 dividend was actually payed out to the account after tax?

[image]

And how do I read the lower table with the first row in AUD being a positive value and the two bottom ones being a negative value? How can the total dividend be negative or be 0?

The Help of IB is not getting me closer:
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/reportguide/reportguide/changeindividendaccruals_mtm.htm

Grateful for beginner-friendly explanations.

Comment: https://ibkr.info/article/2736 This definition is helpful. An "accrual" in IB-speak is like a prognosis of what will be: "While the actual dividend amount is not assured until the payment has been made by the issuer on the Payment Date, information deemed reliable is available such that IB will accrue the value of the dividend, net of any withholding taxes, on the Ex-Date."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IB's statements are a PITA and will make you want to pull your hair out, if you have any.

I don't know what's going on from the info you posted.  But let's take a stab at it.

The upper highlighted box containing 36.08 is simple.  It the 21 shares times the dividend rate of 1.71816941.  They are withholding 5.41 so your net amount is 30.67 .  That's the easy part.

When IB pays interest or a  dividend, they do an Accrual Reversal and they list it as a negative number.  So on the date of payment, they would list lines 1 and 3 of the first 3 rows that you highlighted below.  That's showing that you have a dividend credit  (Line One with the code "Po") and when  it is transferred to your account balance on the Pay Date, they add the debit line (Line Three with the code "Re")..  The question remains, what is Line Two where the net debit is -32.16?

From your link it says:

"At the bottom of this section is the Ending Dividend Accruals in Base Currency. The postings (with code Po) are done for new accrual additions to the account. The reversals (with code Re) are done for the following three reasons: correction in dividend accruals, cancellation in dividend accrual, and reversal due to payout in cash."

My guess is that they posted an incorrect  dividend of 30.67 (Line One) and then reversed it (Line Three).  They then deducted the corrected dividend of 37.84 on Line Two (32.16 after the 5.68 withholding).  When converted to EUR, the credit is 26.73 (22.71 after the 4.01 withholding).  So if you see an account credit of either 32.16 AUD or 22.71 EUR on the Pay Date then my guess is correct.  If not, this has been a waste of our time :->) and you should call IB.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have not found yet where I can see interest or dividend payments to my account other than in those statements. It seems connected to the previous month's dividend records.. confusing

Comment: You're welcome. Assuming that our statements are laid out the same, look at your 1/25/17 statement (the Pay Date).  On the front page, click  box titled "Net Asset Value".  When it opens up, it should show two dates of position info.  There should be a line titled "Dividend Accruals".  If that was indeed the Pay Date, the total from 1/24/17 will be reduced by the amount credited to your account (1/25 numbers). Also on the main page under "Change in Dividend Accruals", you should also see the "Position Reversal". Lastly, your cash balance should increase by the amount of the dividend payment.